# Pipes, ramda with dynamic arguments

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

```
cons columnDefs = [
   {
     label: 'The_First_Name',
     value: getProp,
     args: ['firstName'] // different number of arguments depending on function
   },
   {
     label: 'City',
     value: getNestedProperty,
     args: ['location', 'city'] 
   }
]

const data = [
  {
     firstName: 'Joe',
     lastName: 'Smith',
     location: {
       city: 'London'
     }
  },
   {
     firstName: 'Anna',
     lastName: 'Andersson',
     location: {
       city: 'Stockholm'
     }
  }
]

const getProp = (object, key) => R.prop(key, object);

const getNestedProperty = (obj, args) => R.path(..args, obj);
```

Ramda pipe to map the data:

```
const tableBuilder = R.pipe(R.map); // some ramda functions in here

const rows = tableBuilder(data, columnDefs);
```

The wanted output:

```
rows output:

[
   {
      The_First_Name: 'Joe',
      city: 'London'
   },
   {
      The_First_Name: 'Anna',
      city: 'Stockholm'
   }
]
```

The key of each row is the `label` property in the `columnDefs`. The value is fetched from the `Ramda` function in the `value` prop together with the arguments defined in the `args` prop.

https://plnkr.co/edit/rOGh4zkyOEF24TLaCZ4e?p=preview

Totally stuck. Is this even possible to do with Ramda? Or is better to do it in plain javascript?

Comment: how is rows and columnDefs related can u plz explain ?

Comment: @KOTIOS. I've updated the variables names to make it a bite more clear.

Comment: your dynamic variable is not clear , can you post atleast 2 proper inputs with values in dynamic variables and its corresponding output

Comment: @KOTIOS. I've added one more example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `applySpec` to create an object from another one:

```
const obj = applySpec({
  The_First_Name: prop('firstName'),
  city: path(['location', 'city'])
})

obj({
  firstName: 'Joe',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  location: {
     city: 'London'
   }
});
//=> {"The_First_Name": "Joe", "city": "London"}
```

Then you can use that function to map over you array:

```js
const data = [
  {
     firstName: 'Joe',
     lastName: 'Smith',
     location: {
       city: 'London'
     }
  },
   {
     firstName: 'Anna',
     lastName: 'Andersson',
     location: {
       city: 'Stockholm'
     }
  }
];

const obj = applySpec({
  The_First_Name: prop('firstName'),
  city: path(['location', 'city'])
})

console.log(

  map(obj, data)

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {applySpec, prop, path, map} = R;</script>
```

---

This is how you transform `columnDefs` into an object that you can use with `applySpec`:

```
const spec = def => ({[def.label]: apply(def.value, def.args)});
const specs = compose(mergeAll, map(spec));
```

```js
const columnDefs = [
   {
     label: 'The_First_Name',
     value: prop,
     args: ['firstName'] // different number of arguments depending on function
   },
   {
     label: 'City',
     value: path,
     args: [['location', 'city']]
   }
]

const data = [
  {
     firstName: 'Joe',
     lastName: 'Smith',
     location: {
       city: 'London'
     }
  },
   {
     firstName: 'Anna',
     lastName: 'Andersson',
     location: {
       city: 'Stockholm'
     }
  }
]

const spec = def => ({[def.label]: apply(def.value, def.args)});
const specs = compose(mergeAll, map(spec));

console.log(

  map(applySpec(specs(columnDefs)), data)

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {apply, compose, mergeAll, map, prop, path, applySpec} = R;</script>
```

Comment: The columnDefs should be an argument together with data to build the output. The_First_Name and city should be fetched from the label property in the columnDefs.

Comment: You should be able to generate the object passed on to `applySpec` from your `columnDefs` array.

Comment: Very nice.  But see my answer for a problem with `prop` here.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```js
const tableBuilder = (objs, spec) => objs .map (
  obj => Object .assign ( ...spec.map (
    ( {label, value, args} ) => ( { [label]: value (obj, args) } )
  ))
)

const getProp = (object, key) => R.prop (key, object);

const getNestedProperty = (obj, args) => R.path (args, obj);

const columnDefs = [
   {label: 'The_First_Name', value: getProp, args: ['firstName']},
   {label: 'City', value: getNestedProperty, args: ['location', 'city']}
]

const data = [
  {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Smith', location: {city: 'London'}},
  {firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'Andersson', location: {city: 'Stockholm'}}
]

console .log (
  tableBuilder (data, columnDefs)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script> <script>
const {prop, path} = R                                                         </script>
```

But it's working mostly by happenstance.  You might need to rethink a bit how your functions are defined.

This is calling the equivalent of `prop (['firstName'], obj)`, which happens to work like `prop ('firstName', obj)`, but only for the same reason that `'foo' + ['bar']` yields `'foobar'`.  It's a coincidence you probably should not depend upon.

The trouble is that you want to treat uniformly functions that take a single argument and ones that take an array of arguments. This is a problem.  You probably need to make this consistent.

While you can write a Ramda gloss on this, I'm not sure it will be any more readable.  Perhaps replacing `Object .assign (...spec.map (` with `mergeAll (spec.map (` would be cleaner.  And if you don't mind changing parameter orders, there is probably a bit more clean-up.  But this is already fairly readable.

### Update

The answer from @customcommander convinced me that Ramda really could add some value here.  This requires that you be willing to swap the parameter order for your `value` functions, and to be willing to call it as a fully curried function (`tableBuilder (columnDefs) (data)`), but it does lead to some pretty nice code.

This is mostly the work of customcommander, but I adjusted it a bit to make a more readable function:

```js
const spec = ({label, value, args}) => ({[label]: value(args)})

const tableBuilder = pipe(
  map(spec),
  mergeAll,
  applySpec,
  map
)

const columnDefs = [
   {label: 'The_First_Name', value: prop, args: ['firstName']},
   {label: 'City', value: path, args: ['location', 'city']}
]

const data = [
  {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Smith', location: {city: 'London'}},
  {firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'Andersson', location: {city: 'Stockholm'}}
]


console .log (
  tableBuilder (columnDefs) (data)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script><script>
const {prop, path, pipe, map, mergeAll, applySpec} = R                        </script>
```

This has the same issue as before with `prop`, but do note that you can replace it here with `path` without harm.  The main point is that all your `value` functions should have the same inputs (an array of values and the object to work on.)  If they do, then this should work for any of them.